# Adding Dummy/Blank Member to Report Script in Essbase

Tags: report, hyperion, essbase

Right off the bat, I'll say I'm new to essbase and am far from an expert on report scripts so I'm sure I'm messing up the terminology here, so let me know and I can edit the post.

I'm creating 2 simple report scripts that pull from separate databases and want to combine the output into one file for a load into a new database. However, the two databases do not have the same dimensions but I'd like to add some dummy members to one report script so that everything lines up correctly for an easy merge later.

I'll try and provide some code to paint a picture of this, but it just boils down to whether or not I can add a blank member or not.

```
<COLUMN("Year")
"Year"

<ROW ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"
[[BLANK MEMBER HERE]]
"E"
"F"
"G"

!
```

I tried using the Duplicate function, but this duplicates the entire row and not just the member. It is also worth mentioning that while I could do this after the scripts have ran using a unix script, I'd like to avoid the route if there's something I can do within the essbase script itself.

I've done quite a bit of research on this but haven't been able to find anything, so let me know what you guys think.

Comment: Do you have to combine the files? You could always just load one file with a particular load rule and the other file with a different load rule. The different load rule can easily handle putting in the missing dimensions. I'd much rather do the adjustment on the load rule than in the report script. If you absolutely have to adjust your output it might be easier to use a command line tool like `awk` or similar to process the text file.

Comment: Yes, but I just wanted to see if there was some command that I wasn't seeing to do this. For what its worth, I'm currently just combining the files using a unix script. I have many files and find its easier just combine them with a unix script (probably just personal preference)

Comment: I don't think there's a command you're missing that would do this. You could potentially get creative with some sort of dynamic calculation but I don't think it'd be worth it. If you're already using a Unix script for some processing, then I would definitely look at `awk` or `sed` to tweak the output to match what you want in the target (assuming you want one load file and one load rule). Otherwise, it would be very common to just create a new load rule for the different format and do a multi-step load.